# What meaning does 早く良くなるといいですね have?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a conversation with my language partner.

For some context:

> 階段から落ちたそうですが、大丈夫ですか。骨折はしていなくて、右足のじん帯を痛めたのですね。早く良くなるといいですね。

The sentence in question:

> 早く良くなるといいですね。

My translation:
"When it recovers/you recover quickly, it is good."

Now, this sentence isn't really much of a problem for me. I just would like to know what nuance is expressed through the use of the と conditional particle. 
Does it express something along the lines of "hopefully"? "Hopefully it/you will recover quickly."? Because I just recently was looking for an adverb or the like to express "hopefully", and unfortunately I only found this http://jisho.org/search/hopefully. So maybe the pattern used by my language partner can be used to express this?

Comment: I would add that it's often just as useful or more to search Jisho for sentences rather than words. In this case you would have found this: http://jisho.org/search/hopefully%20%23sentences

Answer (score 2):

Naturally translated it would equate to "I hope you(he/she/they) get better soon."
Literally it means something like "if [subject] gets better soon, it will be good."
といい is often used like this to express "I hope~". There is no nuance of "hopefully" from と. といい is basically "If... ~ ...good"

Comment: In American English we often use "hopefully" and "I hope" interchangeably.

Comment: @mamster Far from just American English - I think that's a universal thing.